# How to generate a random string using Twig?

Tags: php, twig

I have an input that holds the code for a coupon. Users can fill in a custom code, but I'd like to give them a default code. I have the following code now:

```
<input type="text" name="code" value="{{ form.code|default(RANDOM_CODE) }}">
```

And I want to replace `RANDOM_CODE` by a random string.

I don't think that is relevant to the question, but `form.code` contains the original coupon code. I use the same form for editing.

According to Twig docs, it's possible to generate random numbers using `random()`, or even get a random char from within a string using `random('abcdefgh...')`, but I'd like to generate a random string with a specific length.

I know that I can do that using at least two approaches:

1. generating a default random code in the controller and then passing it to the view; or
2. creating a Twig extension with a function to generate the random string for me.

Knowing that I'm curious if there is a way to generate a random string using only Twig's built-in functions.

Comment: I think it is possible to create variables with Twig. You could randomize multiple characters, using a loop, by generating a single random character each time and appending. Would this work?

Comment: @rnevius, yes. And I said that in my question.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, it seems that will work. I could use a `for` loop giving a range, like `{% for i in 0..10 %}` to create a string with 10 characters in length, for instance. But using this approach I'll need to add a `random('abcdefghi...')` inside the loop. I was thinking in something more compact, but I'm almost sure it's not possible.

Comment: Sounds like you have a plan!

Comment: I do this pretty often by simply appending a random number to a prefix. E.g.: `{% set code='prefix-' ~ random() %}`. Do length by using a range. 10 characters? 'prefix-' is 7, need 3 more... `random([100..999])` - random number with 3 digits.

Answer (score 16):

This code will generate a 10 character password in base64 (A to Z in lower and uppercase, 0 to 9, and dash and underscore). This also makes it url friendly. You can change the parameters to your liking if you like.

```
{% set randomPassword = [] %}
{% set alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' %}
{% set numbers = '0123456789' %}

{% for i in 1..10 %}
    {% set randomCharacter = random(alpha ~ alpha|upper ~ numbers ~ '-_') %}
    {% set randomPassword = randomPassword|merge([randomCharacter]) %}
{% endfor %}
{% set randomPassword = randomPassword|join %}


{{ randomPassword }}
```

Comment: This is exactly the thing twig was created not to do.

Comment: @Fluffy probably not for this purpose, but generating random strings has utility in html for generating (arbitrary, but sometimes necessary and possibly repeating) unique IDs for elements for example. I think the question is valid, although the purpose here is suspect.

Answer (score 5):

Twig Native:

```
{{ random() }}
```

Visit below link for twig docs.
[Check This]: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/random.html

Comment: If you check the original question, you'll see it mentions `random()`. The limitation is in the length, it's not possible to set a specific length using it.

Comment: ok once You got the string You can slice it with your required number.
{{ '12345'|slice(1, 2) }}
For more info visit Below:
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/slice.html

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with @Fluffy that you shouldn't do it in twig : your coupon code being a data, that will be handled in php, it must be generated in php.

I however got a use case for generating an unique id directly in the template : when only the template is concerned.

I got a form with inputs. I need an id on my inputs, but only to refer them from inside the same template, in the "for" attribute of a label.

As it was generated in a loop, I went up with a simple :

```
{% set domid='msg' ~ loop.index %}
```

Comment: Hey, @Pierre-Olivier Vares. Thanks for your contribution but this is not exactly what I was looking for. It doesn't generate a random string with a specific length. And, as you can see in the question, I knew that "generating a default random code in the controller and then passing it to the view" is a possible approach. It was just a matter of curiosity at that time. However, it doesn't seem achievable.

Comment: To be honest, my comment was more intended to answer similar questions - and particularly the case I encountered :) -, than answering yours. Which may not be the best method, I should concede.

Answer (score 1):

What about this "unique id":

```
{% set uid = "now"|date('Uv') %}
```

Use a unix timestamp `U` with miliseconds `v` if u iteratively generate them u might add more entropy by concatinating a random()